# Creating column that resets itself

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column consisting of increasing integers (starts at 1 and increases to N). I want to create a second column that runs from 1, 2, 3, 4 then resets and starts at 1, 2, 3, ... and so on. Explicitly shown, this is what I desire:

```
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   1
6   2
7   3
8   4
9   1
10  2
11  3
12  4
13  1
14  2
15  3
... ...
```

Do you have a hint as to how I can do this in SQL? Ideally a complete code example?

Comment: May I ask why you want to to that? What if rows are deleted? I think you should not rely on rows having specific autogenerated values like 1...4.

Comment: I *assume* it's intentional that your data is missing the value `4`? Your statement *"starts at 1 and increases to N"* implies the values should be continuous.

Comment: @Larnu That was a mistake on my behalf, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: So can a number *never* be missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try to number the rows with `ROW_NUMBER()` and add a simple calculation:

```
SELECT Column1, ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Column1) - 1) % 4) + 1 AS Column2
FROM Yourtable
```

Answer (score 1):

If, based on the statement *"starts at 1 and increases to N"*, that the numbers between 1 and `N` must be continuous, then there's actually no need for `ROW_NUMBER` at all; you can just apply the logic to your column `Column1`:

```sql
SELECT Column1,
       ((Column1 - 1) % 4) + 1 AS SequenceColumn
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```